# difference between git command - checkout and switch

Tags: git, version-control

What's the difference between
`git checkout -b branch_name` vs `git switch -c branch_name`?

I tried git command -h as a way to find solution and I was looking for it in documantation. In neither way I managed to find it. In git's documantation I've found this:

> Note that this will create the new branch, but it will not switch the
>   working tree to it; use "git switch " to switch to the new
>   branch.

but either way I typed checkout or switch commnad, my current branch was changed.

Comment: Why are you assuming that there *is* a difference? `git switch` has been introduced in recent versions along with `git restore` in order to split the quite different functions that the old `git checkout` was unecessarily grouping in the same command. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Tbh. having two commands that do the very same thing is not very common so assuming that there should be a difference between the two is quite natural.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, as it was mentioned in the comments there is no actual difference between `git switch` & `git checkout` in terms of what You can do with branches.

The idea to create the `git switch` & `git restore` because they were introduced together, arose from multiple questions & issues that new users had with `git checkout`.  Previously, you could use the `git checkout` to `switch` to a different branch, but also you could use it to `restore` changes from some specific commit or even to restore the changes for a single file.

The problem that was noticed by some of the users is the fact that operation on commits/files & operation on branches are quite different and having them grouped by a single command can be troublesome. That's why there were two new commands introduced `restore` to allow restoring changes and `switch` to allow operations on branches.

So, to sum up, there is no difference between the `git switch` and `git checkout` in terms of switching branches and there is no difference between `git restore` and `git checkout` in terms of restoring changes for files or commits. You can use them interchangeably. The only thing to have in mind is the fact that `switch` & `restore` are still marked as experimental, so I wouldn't use them for creating long-living scripts or so.